# Xcode error - dyld: Library not loaded won't resolve

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Okay so for whatever reason I decide to send a app to my phone directly via xCode, it always crashes regardless. It doesn't matter if the app is new or old, I have tried everything and the app always crashes on my physical device.

If I run it on an emulator it works great though and there are no issues!

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/PINCache.framework/PINCache
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Truth or Dare
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B72BB38-CAF7-4C05-B9BF-A197463C88B4/Truth or Dare.app/Frameworks/PINCache.framework/PINCache: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

**Update:** I have scoured the whole internet and there is not a single answer has worked.

I have tried setting the Embed setting in Build Settings to YES

I have tried a project rebuild

I have tried making a new user account

I have tried cleaning out the provisioning profiles in my keychain and on my device

I have tried to restart both the MacBook and my iDevice.

I have tried a whole new project.

Comment: Try to Clean build the app `CMD+SHIFT+K` & `CMD+B`

Comment: I've tried that various times @SureshMopidevi

Comment: I found an article regarding to this issue. please take a look https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-on-macos/

Comment: @SureshMopidevi I tried all of that

Comment: I have exactly same error. Did you find fix?

Comment: @Ingun I reinstalled Xcode and restarted the whole app. Overall just completely approached everything in my code differently. It had something to do with code signing though.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I used to be able to run my apps on my physical phone without issue. Wondering if it's something to do with iOS 13 and/or SwiftUI. Did you have any SwiftUI code in yours?

Comment: Also, do you have a full, paid developer license, or are you just using the limited, free version? I'm just on the free version, and wondering if that's a factor as well.

Comment: If you are using a free version, it looks to be specific to some versions of iOS. According this article, it's an issue with iOS 13.3.1, but was also the case with some earlier versions (e.g. Betas of 13.2). Maybe you were using one of those? https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment for a little bit of clarity that, this only happens on iOS 13.3.1 as mentioned above and runs perfectly for earlier iOS's.

Comment: @TheNeil I am on the Paid Developer License

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Solved**
The problem with nothing to do with something I did or could’ve controlled, needless to say that I recoded the whole app from scratch for nothing, even though I like it a whole lot better now.

The problem was the version of iOS I was running. I had used a Beta version of iOS (**iOS 13.3 Beta 3**) and this had for some reason been conflicting with the DeviceSupport folder I added to Xcode and wasn’t working properly.

**If you are here because you are having the same issue, follow the following steps!**

**Method 1: Clean your build**
 - Open the damaged project
 - CMD + SHIFT + K
 - CMD + B

**Method 2: Reset Keychain to Default**
 *• THIS WILL RESET YOUR KEYCHAIN •
 - Open Keychain Access
 - Select Keychain Access > Preferences
 - Select General
 - Select Reset My Default Keychain

**Method 3: Reset Certificates on Device**
 - Open Xcode
 - Connect affected iDevice
 - Press CMD + Shift + 2
 - Right Click Device
 - Select View Provisioning Profiles
 - Delete any profiles that pertain to your app

**Method 4: Reinstall the latest supported version of iOS**
 *If you haven’t installed any beta versions of iOS, you can ignore this*
 - Back up your device in case anything goes wrong!
 - Go download the latest stage version of iOS that in the form of IPSW and is signed
 - Connect iDevice to computer
 - Select Restore while pressing (SHIFT/CMD) and then select the downloaded IPSW file and wait.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, there's still issues on this in iOS 13.3.1 specifically, at least for non-paid developer certificates. Worth knowing, as the issue might still persist for some. Here's an example discussion on the topic: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051

Comment: @TheNeil I wouldn’t know because I haven’t used Alamofire and wasn’t using it in this scenario.

Comment: Nor am I. It's not an issue specific to Alamofire - it applies to any framework. That's just one discussion where it's covered in detail.

Comment: The point is that the issue still exists in iOS 13.3.1 for anyone without a paid developer license.

Comment: @TheNeil the issue occurs for any signing of files that are being compiled by a account that does not have developer access

Comment: Exactly, and the article states that this issue still persists in iOS 13.3.1, not just the Beta versions. That's why I'm pointing it out: because it doesn't appear to be fully fixed yet. Worth knowing.

Comment: @TheNeil this all happened around the time that Apple broke Cydia Impactor, I think Apple is going to be restricting iOS development to strictly only Developer Program Members over time and this is a sign of that

Comment: FYI, this issue is now also fully fixed for non-paid developers as of iOS 13.5 (it may also have been fixed in 13.4, but I didn't install that due to its other issues).